Login Route and Controller
My Blade file code is like below.
<form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post" class="row mt-4 align-items-center">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="mb-3 col-sm-12">
        <label class="form-label">Email Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 col-sm-12">
        <label class="form-label">Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-checkbox" title="{{ __('Remember Me') }}">
            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="remember" value="1">
            <label class="fw-normal" for="rememberMe">{{ __('Remember Me') }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3col-sm-6 d-grid">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
    </div>
</form>

According to blade file there will be a route like below in routes/web.php file.
Route::post('login', [])->name('');

But I am not getting any login route like above in routes/web.php file.
Where is the controller of this Form  where it is submitting ?
How it is redirecting ?

Are you using breeze? If so, then the auth routes will be in routes\auth.php. If you check the bottom of your web.php you should see something like require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';

Thanks @Mr.Kenneth. There is no routes\auth.php in my routes folder.

When using Laravel UI for authentication, you can enable authentication routes by calling Auth::routes() in your routes/web.php file. This automatically registers all necessary authentication routes such as login, registration, password reset, and more. These routes are typically protected by the auth middleware, ensuring that only authenticated users can access certain areas of the application.
Additionally, you will find controllers related to authentication in the app/Http/Controllers/Auth folder.
php artisan route:list use this command to show all the routes

To define the form action with a Laravel web route, you define the route in your routes/web.php like this:
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'loginSubmit'])->name('login');


The URL login is mapped to the loginSubmit method of the
LoginController
The route is named login using the name method. This is useful for
generating URLs or redirects using the route's name.

One more suggestion: regarding to csrf token:
Instead of manual input type hidden for csrf, you can use built-in feature for csrf as follows:
<form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf       
    ----
</form>


use below command in terminal to get all your laravel routes based on their name,this will help you to find all routes
php artisan route:list --name

and look it up for the route named "login" and then its controller will be found easily
